# Display content outside container in bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, grid-layout, fluid-layout

I have a slider that I need to fit its content within the bootstrap container. However, I want to put the pager outside the container. This is my logic but it doesn't work.

```
<div class="container-fluid"><!-- a wrapper for the slider and its pager -->
<div class="pager">
my pager content
</div>
<div class="slidercontent container"><!-- so that the slider content fits within the container area with the normal margins-->
my slider content
</div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: please provide link or fiddle for the same

Answer (score 1):

CSS:

```
.pager{
    position:absolute;
    left:-50px;
}
```

Can't see your code though...